# Python 3 scrapy DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET https...> (referer: https...)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and I want to crawl some users' data from Weibo, a Twitter-type website from China. I kept recieving this when I ran "scrapy crawl weibo_spider -o data.csv":

```py
2019-11-10 17:49:10 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET https://weibo.cn/2803301701/info> (referer: None)
2019-11-10 17:49:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET https://weibo.cn/u/2803301701> (referer: https://weibo.cn/2803301701/info)
2019-11-10 17:49:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <302 https://weibo.cn/u/2803301701>
{'_id': '2803301701', 'crawl_time': 1573379351}
2019-11-10 17:49:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET https://weibo.cn/2803301701/profile?page=1> (referer: https://weibo.cn/u/2803301701)
2019-11-10 17:49:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://weibo.cn/2803301701/profile?page=1> (referer: https://weibo.cn/u/2803301701)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/lveshengyichou/Documents/WeiboSpider-simple/sina/spiders/weibospikder.py", line 121, in parse_tweet
    tweet_nodes = tree_node.xpath('//div[@class="c" and @id]')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

The error was in the last line. However I recognized that the reason why I had a "NoneType" object should be the "DEBUG: Crawled (302) ...". I have no idea about how to deal with these errors.
Here are some of my codes:

```py
class WeiboSpider(Spider):
    name = "weibo_spider"
    base_url = "https://weibo.cn"

    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]

    def start_requests(self):
        start_uids = [
            '2803301701', 
        ]
        for uid in start_uids:
            yield Request(url="https://weibo.cn/%s/info" % uid, callback=self.parse_information)

    def parse_information(self, response):
        information_item = InformationItem()
        information_item['crawl_time'] = int(time.time())
        selector = Selector(response)
        information_item['_id'] = re.findall('(\d+)/info', response.url)[0]
        text1 = ";".join(selector.xpath('body/div[@class="c"]//text()').extract())
        nick_name = re.findall('昵称;?[：:]?(.*?);', text1)
        gender = re.findall('性别;?[：:]?(.*?);', text1)
        place = re.findall('地区;?[：:]?(.*?);', text1)
        briefIntroduction = re.findall('简介;?[：:]?(.*?);', text1)
        birthday = re.findall('生日;?[：:]?(.*?);', text1)
        sex_orientation = re.findall('性取向;?[：:]?(.*?);', text1)
        sentiment = re.findall('感情状况;?[：:]?(.*?);', text1)
        vip_level = re.findall('会员等级;?[：:]?(.*?);', text1)
        authentication = re.findall('认证;?[：:]?(.*?);', text1)
        labels = re.findall('标签;?[：:]?(.*?)更多>>', text1)
        if nick_name and nick_name[0]:
            information_item["nick_name"] = nick_name[0].replace(u"\xa0", "")
        if gender and gender[0]:
            information_item["gender"] = gender[0].replace(u"\xa0", "")
        if place and place[0]:
            place = place[0].replace(u"\xa0", "").split(" ")
            information_item["province"] = place[0]
            if len(place) > 1:
                information_item["city"] = place[1]
        if briefIntroduction and briefIntroduction[0]:
            information_item["brief_introduction"] = briefIntroduction[0].replace(u"\xa0", "")
        if birthday and birthday[0]:
            information_item['birthday'] = birthday[0]
        if sex_orientation and sex_orientation[0]:
            if sex_orientation[0].replace(u"\xa0", "") == gender[0]:
                information_item["sex_orientation"] = "同性恋"
            else:
                information_item["sex_orientation"] = "异性恋"
        if sentiment and sentiment[0]:
            information_item["sentiment"] = sentiment[0].replace(u"\xa0", "")
        if vip_level and vip_level[0]:
            information_item["vip_level"] = vip_level[0].replace(u"\xa0", "")
        if authentication and authentication[0]:
            information_item["authentication"] = authentication[0].replace(u"\xa0", "")
        if labels and labels[0]:
            information_item["labels"] = labels[0].replace(u"\xa0", ",").replace(';', '').strip(',')
        request_meta = response.meta
        request_meta['item'] = information_item
        yield Request(self.base_url + '/u/{}'.format(information_item['_id']),
                      callback=self.parse_further_information,
                      meta=request_meta, dont_filter=True, priority=1)

    def parse_further_information(self, response):
        text = response.text
        information_item = response.meta['item']
        tweets_num = re.findall('微博\[(\d+)\]', text)
        if tweets_num:
            information_item['tweets_num'] = int(tweets_num[0])
        follows_num = re.findall('关注\[(\d+)\]', text)
        if follows_num:
            information_item['follows_num'] = int(follows_num[0])
        fans_num = re.findall('粉丝\[(\d+)\]', text)
        if fans_num:
            information_item['fans_num'] = int(fans_num[0])
        yield information_item

        # tweets
        yield Request(url=self.base_url + '/{}/profile?page=1'.format(information_item['_id']),
                      callback=self.parse_tweet,
                      priority=1)

        # followees
        yield Request(url=self.base_url + '/{}/follow?page=1'.format(information_item['_id']),
                      callback=self.parse_follow,
                      dont_filter=True)
        # followers
        yield Request(url=self.base_url + '/{}/fans?page=1'.format(information_item['_id']),
                      callback=self.parse_fans,
                      dont_filter=True)

    def parse_tweet(self, response):
        if response.url.endswith('page=1'):
            all_page = re.search(r'/>&nbsp;1/(\d+)页</div>', response.text)
            if all_page:
                all_page = all_page.group(1)
                all_page = int(all_page)
                for page_num in range(2, all_page + 1):
                    page_url = response.url.replace('page=1', 'page={}'.format(page_num))
                    yield Request(page_url, self.parse_tweet, dont_filter=True, meta=response.meta)
        """
        解析本页的数据
        """
        tree_node = etree.HTML(response.body)
        tweet_nodes = tree_node.xpath('//div[@class="c" and @id]')
        ...
```

The last line is the ERROR. I found this code from github, except the fourth line "handle_httpstatus_list = [302]" was added by myself.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why did you add `handle_httpstatus_list` in the first place?

Comment: Because otherwise I will get an error like this:
DEBUG: Ignoring response <302 https...>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed.
I found this line from another post.@Gallaecio

Comment: Have you disabled the redirect middleware?